# Do the shire-folk know what Frodo and the Fellowship did?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

After the events of *The Lord of The Rings*; [The Shire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shire_(Middle-earth)) is [left under somewhat of a protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shire_(Middle-earth)#History) by **[King Aragorn "Elessar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragorn)**.

Following *[The Scouring of The Shire](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Scouring_of_the_Shire)*, **[Frodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frodo_Baggins)** becomes deputy Mayor, and **[Sam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samwise_Gamgee)** gets elected as Mayor<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayor_of_the_Shire)</sup>.

**Do the Shire-folk know what Frodo and company did, in regards to the events of The One Ring?**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In general, no (emphasis mine):

> All things now went well, with hope always of becoming still better; and Sam was as busy and as full of delight as even a hobbit could wish. Nothing for him marred that whole year, except for some vague anxiety about his master. **Frodo dropped quietly out of all the doings of the Shire, and Sam was pained to notice how little honour he had in his own country. Few people knew or wanted to know about his deeds and adventures**; their admiration and respect were given mostly to Mr. Meriadoc and Mr. Peregrin and (if Sam had known it) to himself. Also in the autumn there appeared a shadow of old troubles.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Book VI Chapter 9: "The Grey Havens"</sub></sup>

It seems vastly more plausible that Merry and Pippin are as highly regarded as they are for their role in the Scouring of the Shire, and Sam for his clean-up efforts in the aftermath.

Frodo later on suggests that Sam will tell the story, and so the hobbits will *come* to know about the events of the War of the Ring:

> You will be the Mayor, of course, as long as you want to be, and the most famous gardener in history; and you will read things out of the Red Book, and keep alive the memory of the age that is gone. so that people will remember the Great Danger and so love their beloved land all the more.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Book VI Chapter 9: "The Grey Havens"</sub></sup>

We know from the Prologue that Sam preserved knowledge of the Red book within his own family:

> The original Red Book has not been preserved, but many copies were made, especially of the first volume, for the use of the descendants of the children of Master Samwise.
>
> <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Prologue 5: *Note on Shire Records*</sub></sup>

But we don't know how widespread this knowledge was in the Shire, or among the hobbits of Frodo's time.

Comment: We do because copies of the red book survived long enough for Tolkien to find and translate it :-)

Comment: I agree they knew. Whether they _cared_ may be another question, since it happened in foreign parts and it came out all right in the end. Remember how the children's-story of "Mad Baggins, who would disappear with a flash and reappear with a bag of gold" persisted long after the true facts had been forgotten... which says they did fade into history.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Well, [we know that copies were made and preserved by Sam's family, and in Gondor](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102630/how-did-j-r-r-tolkien-learn-about-the-events-of-his-books-in-universe). We don't know how widespread the knowledge was in the Shire